# Buffer size for capturing packets in kernel space?

Tags: kernel, networking, buffer, tcpdump

Going through the man page of `tcpdump`, it seems kernel can drop the packets if the buffer is full. I was wondering if:

1. that size is configurable and/or
2. where can I see the size for my distro?

From the man page (for easy reference):

> packets ``dropped by kernel'' (this is the number of packets that were dropped, due to a lack of buffer space, by the packet capture mechanism in the OS on which tcpdump is running, if the OS reports that information to applications; if not, it will be reported as 0).

Answer (score 30):

Tcpdump has the option `-B` to set the capture buffer size. 
The value is then passed to libpcap (library used by tcpdump
to do the actual packet capturing)
via the `pcap_set_buffer_size()` function. 
[tcpdump(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tcpdump.1.html) (tcpdump's man page) says that the capture buffer size
is specified in units of KiB (1024 bytes);
the [source](https://github.com/mcr/tcpdump/blob/2c0a8eb4eb535eb1863e18497cd7dff54cc0d97e/tcpdump.c#L673) seems to confirm this.

[pcap_set_buffer_size(3pcap)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pcap_set_buffer_size.3pcap.html) (pcap_set_buffer_size's man page)
does not specify the default buffer size
(which is used if this function is not called),
but again, from the [libpcap source](https://github.com/mcr/libpcap/blob/9b67fb6b670d255f496fcdf280a7cf8692137ea2/pcap-linux.c#L3396), this seems to be 2 MiB, 
at least on Linux (but is most likely system dependent).

With regard to packet buffering and dropping,
you should also pay attention to setting
the snaplen (`-s`) parameter appropriately. 
From [tcpdump(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tcpdump.1.html):

> `-s snaplen` 
> `--snapshot-length=snaplen`
>
>   Snarf
>   *snaplen*
>   bytes of data from each packet rather than the
>   default of 65535
>   <sup>1</sup>
>   bytes. 
>   Packets truncated because of a limited snapshot
>   are indicated in the output with ‘‘[
>   `|proto`
>   ]’’,
>   where
>   *`proto`*
>   is the name of the protocol level
>   at which the truncation has occurred.
>
> Note that taking larger snapshots
> both increases the amount of time it takes to process packets
> and, effectively, decreases the amount of packet buffering. 
> This may cause packets to be lost. 
>            ︙ 
>         ... you should limit *snaplen* to the smallest number
> that will capture the protocol information you're interested in. 
> Setting *snaplen* to 0 sets it to the default of 65535<sup>1</sup>,
> for backwards compatibility with recent older versions of `tcpdump`.

________________ 
    <sup>1</sup> Recent versions of the man page
say 262144 rather than 65535 (both places).

This means that with a fixed buffer size,
you can increase the number of packets that fit into the buffer
(and thus not being dropped)
by decreasing the *`snaplen`* size.

Comment: I know this is an old thread (and I like this answer), but when you cite sources on GitHub, please point to the current commit (as the master branch can change), e.g.: https://github.com/mcr/tcpdump/blob/2c0a8eb4eb535eb1863e18497cd7dff54cc0d97e/tcpdump.c#L673.

Comment: @brunonery That is not a problem with Stack Exchange sites, where we actually encourage users to improve answers, even if the post itself is quite old. (Unlike forums where it is frowned upon.)

Comment: fixed the outdated links