# How to display all data using tcpdump?

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I am capturing network traffic by using `tcpdump`. The problem is, I can't see all capture data when the package is too long. For example, when the tcp frame length more than 500,I just see 100-200 or less. How to display all frame data(500+)? I have tried add `-vv` and `-vvv` parameter. This is my command:

```
tcpdump -i eth1 tcp and host 10.27.13.14 and port 6973 -vv -X -c 1000
```

Comment: Does adding `-s0` capture all that you need?

Comment: @clk I have added but don't pay attention at  that time,it works,thank you!

Comment: s0 may help or not depending on the type of traffic and what you are doing; while it might apply for this case, please see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254280/tcpdump-lost-packets ; @clk would you write a proper answer to get points?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-s` snaplen flag to specify the size of each packet.

`-s 0` sets the default packet size to 65535 bytes, which increases how long it takes to process packets and decreases the amount of packet buffering, according to the man page. Though this might work here, it may not be appropriate in other cases as it can cause packets to be lost.

A better practice would be to set the `snaplen` flag to the smallest value needed to capture what's needed. [Another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254280/tcpdump-lost-packets) suggests 1500 bytes to see the whole packet and 160 bytes if you're only interested in the headers.

So, while `-s 0` may work here, for future use it would be a better idea to start with `-s 1500` and adjust as needed.

From `man tcpdump`:

> Note that taking larger snap-shots both increases the amount of time
>   it takes to  process  packets  and, effectively,  decreases  the 
>   amount  of  packet buffering.  This may cause packets to be lost.  You
>   should limit snaplen to the smallest  number  that will  capture  the 
>   protocol  information  you're  interested  in. Setting snaplen to 0
>   sets it to the default of 65535, for  backwards  compatibility with
>   recent older versions of tcpdump.